# QWindow::showMinimized() doesn't work, bug?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

In macOS 10.13.6 - Qt 5.13.0
I found the showMaximized() and showNormal() are work, but showMinimized() doesn't work.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    id: root
    width: 890
    height: 600
    minimumWidth: 890
    minimumHeight: 600
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window

    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        anchors.verticalCenterOffset: -25
        width: 200
        height: 50
        color: "#556699"
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "minimized window"
            font.pointSize: 20
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                console.log("minimized button clicked")
                root.showMinimized()
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 45
        width: 200
        height: 50
        color: "#886699"
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "maximized window"
            font.pointSize: 20
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                console.log("maximized button clicked")
                if(root.width === Screen.width) {
                    root.showNormal()
                } else {
                    root.showMaximized()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you run this code, you will find the "minimized window" button doesn't work, but the another one work fine.
I found this to be related to "flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window", which is fine when I remove it.

Comment: My only suspicion is that root wouldn't be a window, because showMinimized() only applies to windows, even when it is declared as a member of widget.

Comment: @eyllanesc and @ Pedro
Thanks.I revised the question again.

Comment: @senlinmu In Linux-Qt 5.13.1 it works correctly

Comment: @eyllanesc Aha, that means that it is really a bug? It doesn't work in Mac10.13.6 -Qt 5.13.0.

Comment: @senlinmu If it should work and does not work then it is very likely to be a bug, and if the problem is only seen in an OS that reinforces the idea, reports the bug